# Not able to pass datetime in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner in software field. And I have problem in passing Datetime to a class constructor. So there is one ASP.Net MVC 5 application and it interacts with VB.net code for backend work. (Humor me on this).

Here is what I have till now.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class Add
{
    public DateTime? dateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLocationBlock(Add viewModel)
{
        if(viewModel.dateTime !=null)
        {
            ClsArgs obj1 = new ClsArgs((viewModel.dateTime);   
                                                     ^^ ERROR: matching constructor not found                                                             
        }    
        return new EmptyResult();
}
```

**VB.net constructor definition:**

```
 public ClsArgs(DateTime ExpirationDate);
```

Below solution works:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddLocationBlock(Add viewModel)
    {
            if(viewModel.dateTime !=null)
            {
                DateTime dte = new DateTime();
                ClsArgs obj1 = new ClsArgs(dte);                                    
            }    
            return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, you have this: `ClsArgs((viewModel.dateTime);` in your first controller block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to send a [`Nullable<DateTime>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) (this is what DateTime? actually means it's just a shorter version of writing it) and your constructor takes a `DateTime`.
You have to use the `Value` to get the actual `DateTime`, after you've checked for null or `HasValue` otherwise you'll get an exception if it's actually null.

Change this

```
ClsArgs obj1 = new ClsArgs(viewModel.dateTime)
```

to this

```
ClsArgs obj1 = new ClsArgs(viewModel.dateTime.Value)
```

Comment: @Unbreakable Read up on nullables. They are as robert says an object with a specific type `Nullable<T>`. You check whether the variable is `null` with help of the `.HasValue` property. If that returns `true`, then you will find the value of the object in the `.Value` property of the variable.

Comment: Understood, so datetime is not like a primitive datatypes. its more like a class and thus to access the value I need the instance and then the DOT operator. Thank you!

Comment: But the confusion still comes. because in the constructor I am expecting whole DateTime Object. Not a particular value out of it.

Comment: @Unbreakable, if I explained it wrong than I'm sorry, but it's exactly the opposite of what you said. DateTime behaves exactly like int, double and so on, The reason you have to use the dot operator is because you added the ?. DateTime comes from [ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) like all the structs in c#

Comment: Got it. Thank you. :)